# How to define custom health check endpoint for gRPC in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, spring-boot-actuator, grpc-java

I wanted to define a custom gRPC health check in my gRPC service. I wrote this class for that:

```
@Slf4j
@GRpcService
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HealthCheckService extends HealthGrpc.HealthImplBase{
  @Override
  public void check(
      final io.grpc.health.v1.HealthCheckRequest request,
      final io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<io.grpc.health.v1.HealthCheckResponse>
          responseObserver) {

    final HealthCheckResponse response;
    if (someCondition()) {
      response = HealthCheckResponse.newBuilder()
          .setStatus(ServingStatus.NOT_SERVING)
          .build();
      log.info("********gRPC health check ==== NOT_SERVING ********");
    } else {
      response = HealthCheckResponse.newBuilder()
          .setStatus(HealthCheckResponse.ServingStatus.SERVING)
          .build();
      log.info("********gRPC health check ==== SERVING ********");
    }
    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
  }
}
```

However, running the Springboot application gives this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.lognet.springboot.grpc.recovery.GRpcExceptionHandlerMethodResolver]: Factory method 'exceptionHandlerMethodResolver' threw exception with message: Duplicate key grpc.health.v1.Health (attempted merging values com.company.unit.customgrpcservice.grpc.HealthCheckService@4b37b01e and org.lognet.springboot.grpc.health.DefaultHealthStatusService$$SpringCGLIB$$0@46d52510)
```

How do I disable the default health check and provide the custom one?

Comment: Why do you think there is a default health check enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter,

you just configure :

grpc.server.health-service-enabled to false

like this:
grpc.server.health-service-enabled=false